# How to include a variable in a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my JavaScript, I have a variable called `counter`. And I want to append it to a select tag's ID that I dynamically created using my script like-

```
// Creating a <div>
var random_div = $(document.createElement('div'))
                 .attr("class", "col-md-7");

counter = 5;

random_div.after().html('<select multiple class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="tal' + counter + '" id="tal' + counter + '" > </select>');

random_div.appendTo(main_div);
```

Now, I'm trying to resolve width of this newly created `select` tag, but it doesn't work-

```
$("#tal" + counter).select2({width: 'resolve'});
```

I even tried it with another variable, but that doesn't work either-

```
var testing = '#tal' + counter;
$(testing).select2({width: 'resolve'});
```

Now, if I hard-code this to say `$("#tal5").select2({width: 'resolve'});`, it works.

This is really elementary, but I can't seem to figure out a solution.

Comment: In your hard coded example, did you mean "#tal5"? Or did "tal5" work?

Comment: my mistake, updated the question

Comment: You have verified that `counter` contains `5`?

Comment: Yes, I did a console.log to verify that

Comment: It works here https://jsfiddle.net/mfkygqd2/

Comment: Can you show an example of the generated HTML after it's been injected?

Comment: I am not seeing issue with selector may be something wrong with counter.

Comment: why is there a `</div>` in the select code? This will be hard to debug without an example that shows the problem. Code should work so maybe it is something else.'

Comment: What is with the `after()`??

Comment: @epascarello removed the div, my bad

Comment: @Keith doesn't work with my `select` tag

Comment: seems to work here too https://jsfiddle.net/mfkygqd2/

Comment: @epascarello `after()` is used to create a dynamic div on a button click. Once that div is generated, I create my `select` tag using `.html()` and then I resolve its width.

Comment: sorry i updated the wrong one https://jsfiddle.net/k2yxj89h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not look up the element, generate the element with jQuery and use the reference

```
const select = $('<select ...></select'); // make the select
yourElem.append(select) // add it
select.select2({width: 'resolve'}); // fire the select2
```

Comment: This works great - however, in my actual code, instead of just the `select` tag, I also have `h5` and `div` tags like `<h5> .. </h5> <div>  <select> ...  </select></div>`, and your code gives me an error for that. What would you recommend?

Comment: so select the tag out of it....
`const myElems = $('<div><select></select></div>')
myElems.find("select").select2()`

Comment: Thanks, worked great. Although I still went with my original way of using `after()`, since the spacing between the elements on the page was weird for some reason if I tried your approach. And just added `random_div.find("select").select2({width: 'resolve'});` instead of using the jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

There are some js errors because of miss escaping of single quotes and double quotes

```js
    var random_div = $(document.createElement('div'))
                 .attr("class", "col-md-7");

counter = 5;

random_div.after().html('<select multiple class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="tal'+counter+'" id="tal'+counter+'" > </select>');

  console.log($(random_div).find('#tal'+counter)[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

try this, now its working